# How to enter with landscape mode with a UITabBarController App?

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UITabBarController`, and each tab handles a different `UIViewController` that pushes on the stack new controllers as needed. and every `UIViewController` be created with NIB and included method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

but I found that when I enter the app with Landscape mode, it not work, still with a portrait mode, why?
and for my ipad app, it can work, and in plist have setted "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" and "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)" for all device orientations. and target of xcode enabled "Supported Interface Orientations " button for gray, but still not work for iphone, and ipad will fine, Why? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which iOS are you testing against?

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

Is for iOS5

If you are on iOS6 make sure these are clicked in the application settings. 
[image]

Comment: yes , I  had test all of these, but not working. and I know that all the controller of TabController will be added the delegate method: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation, but still not work , why???

Comment: Again. What iOS version are you testing against.